# proteger/desproteger ficheros en team foundation server desde aplicación c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, control-de-versiones

Buenos días,

Trabajo con 2 proyectos en paralelo que están bajo control de código fuente en un TFS. Cada uno de ellos se utiliza para una serie de desarrollos concretos y como mantenimiento regular hay que sincronizar las carpetas locales para que ambos proyectos mantengan la misma funcionalidad.

¿Habría alguna manera de poder proteger/desproteger ficheros en el tfs desde una aplicación C#? He estado "googleando" un poco y solamente he encontrado información de como conectar al TFS y recuperar la colección de workitems del mismo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Buenas de nuevo,

Mirando por MSDN me he encontrado con un para de namespaces que tienen buena pinta, el **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client** y el **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client**, lo que ocurre que no encuentro nada de código de ejemplo en el msdn.

¿Alguien que las haya usado y me pueda "iluminar" un poco.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizas buscas algo como esto

[Lock and unlock folders or files](https://www.visualstudio.com/es-es/docs/tfvc/lock-unlock-folders-files)

como veras puedes bloquear un archivo, pero entiendo esto funciona si usas el versionado de TFS, si usas Git quizas no funciona

En el Source Control Explorer podrias localizar esta opcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la idea es realizar operaciones en TFS desde codigo podrias hacer uso de la Rest API

[REST API Overview for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview)

tienes la libreria `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`

[.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet)

en el link hay ejemplos de su uso

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Leandro, pero no es lo que estoy buscando.

Comment: Cachis con el enter, yo lo que busco es poder proteger y desproteger ficheros bajo control de código fuente desde una aplicación c#, es decir ejecutar un "Desproteger para editar" y un "Proteger" una vez he sincronizado el código entre los 2 repositorios.

Un saludo.

Comment: no me queda claro lo que quieres conseguir, quieres realizar estas acciones usando codigo ?

Comment: Si, eso mismo, he estado investigando un poco y he visto un paquete  nuget el "Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client" que según la descripción "Trabaja y gestiona el control de versiones", lo que ocurre es que no encuentro nada de documentación sobre la Api del TFS.

Un saludo.

Comment: edite la respuesta, veras que la api tiene documentacion de como usarla y ejemplos, no son muchos pero deberia alcanzar para aprender lo basico y luego inspeccionar el resto de la funcionalidad que expone

Comment: Muchas gracias @Leandro, le echaré un vistazo a esta documentación a ver si consigo sacar algo en claro.

Un saludo.